# Sensu-Client won't start on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, service, sensu

I've installed sensu-core and performed the necessary configurations for sensu-client as per the documentation laid out [here](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/sensu-on-microsoft-windows) for sensu v0.23. I used Windows SC utility to create the Windows service for the Sensu-client and it appears it was done successfully. However I am failing to start the Sensu-client via the Command Prompt and via Services.msc. When trying to force a start using the latter I get `Error 216:0xd8`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?